# 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5

I'm trying to get username by this code in Client App:

```
SimpleService.SimpleServiceClient client = new SimpleService.SimpleServiceClient();
MessageBox.Show(client.GetUserName());
```

The service method is:

```
public string GetUserName()
{
    return "Authenticated Username: " + ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
}
```

This problem appears when Client App uses WCF Service hosted in IIS as Service Reference.
When I use simple WCF Service from project all works great.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: an exception has occured on your service , may be because of Database related issues , try to look into the inner exception for more details

Comment: Are you able to open the service url in your browser?

Comment: @RicardoPontual
Yes, in browser works.